# How to change variable type when working with pandas-profiling?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-analysis, pandas-profiling

**For reproducing the issue, Notebook, data, output: [github link](https://github.com/mohith7548/Pandas-Profiling-issue-recreation)** 
I have Contract variable/column in my dataset which looks like this, all look like numbers but they are actually categorical. 
[image]

When read with pandas, the info says it is read as int. Since the contract variable is a category(from the metadata I received) so I manually changed the variable type like below

```py
df['Contract'] = df['Contract'].astype('categorical')
df.dtypes # shows modified dtype now
```

I then tried to get report from `pandas_profiling`. The generated report shows that `contact` interpreted as real number, even though I changed the type from `int` to `str`/`category`.

```py
# Tried both, but resulted in same.
ProfileReport(df)
df.profile_report()
```

[image]

Can you explain right way to interpret datatypes with `pandas_profiling`? i.e, change `contract` variable to `categorical` type.

Comment: rather than `.astype("categoriat")`, try, `.astype(string)`

Comment: I did that as well `astype('str')` & `astype('category')`. But same result

Comment: I recommend appending a character to the front of each value in that column then (e.g., `9940242774` becomes `"c9940242774"`

Comment: This is exactly what I'm using at the moment. But there has to be some way right? Kindly share the question/upvote/comment for better reachability.

Comment: can you make a reproducible example?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Here's the link to sample/reproducible data: https://github.com/mohith7548/Pandas-Profiling-issue-recreation

Comment: That belongs in the question, not in a gist

Comment: The repo link above has, ipynb file which has dataframe creation step. You can chop the `Contract` column from there.

Comment: copy and paste that info into the question. links rot and and this question won't make any sense

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @PaulH I think notebook in the GitHub link is good enough to understand and it also have comments. Let me know if you need any other info

Comment: I'm telling you that it's not. One day, you're going to clean up your GitHub profile, that link will go away, and future readers who might benefit from this question will be left in the dark.

Comment: I ain't gonna clean up that repo. Kindly go through the ipynb notebook. Here I raised an issue as well https://github.com/pandas-profiling/pandas-profiling/issues/676. Now I understand why you can't answer this question ; )

Comment: @Mohith7548 So looking at your github issue, is the basic conclusion that there is no way to stop the report generator from just inferring the type, end of story?

Comment: @Mohith7548 Actually, just saw your contrib (https://github.com/pandas-profiling/pandas-profiling/issues/676#issuecomment-770263553). You should post this as the answer to your question (would be helpful to others esp. since this info does not appear to be anywhere in the `pandas_profiling` docs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a long time posting this question, [raising issue](https://github.com/pandas-profiling/pandas-profiling/issues/676) and creating a [pull request](https://github.com/pandas-profiling/pandas-profiling/pull/680) for this on `pandas-profiling` GitHub page, I almost forgot this question. I thank [IampShadesDrifter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8236733/lampshadesdrifter) for reminding me to close this question by answering.

Actually this behavior of `pandas-profiling` is expected. `pandas-profiling` tries to infer the data type that best suits for a column. And it is how it's written before. Since there wasn't a solution. it drove me to create my first ever [pull request](https://github.com/pandas-profiling/pandas-profiling/pull/680) on GitHub.

Now with the newly added parameter `infer_dtypes` in `ProfileReport` / `profile_report`, we can explicitly ask `pandas-profiling` not to infer any data type, but rather use the data type from `pandas` (`df.dtypes`).

```py
# for the df in the question,

df['Contract'] = df['Contract'].astype('categorical')

# `Contract` dtype now will be used as `categorical` as type-casted above. 
# And `pandas-profiling` does not infer dtype on its own, rather uses dtypes as understood by pandas
# for this we have to set `infer_dtypes=False`
ProfileReport(df, infer_dtypes=False) # or
df.profile_report(infer_dtypes=False)
```

Please feel free to contribute for this answer, if you found anything worth mentioning.

Comment: It should be infer_dtypes=False right?

Comment: My bad. Feel free to make an edit if needed. Thanks ;)

Comment: Which are other options other than `categorical`? I tried `int` and `integer` but I got `Type not found` on `ydata-profling` package and did not find nothing in its docs.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to override the column type

```
prof = ProfileReport(
    df,
    config_file="config.yaml",
    type_schema={
        "column_1": "categorical",
        "column_2": "categorical",
    }
)
prof.to_file("profile.html")
```

Comment: @Prof.Plague: Please provide accurate edit summaries. Your edit summary for this was unrelated to the edits you made.

Comment: Which are other options other than `categorical`? I tried `int` and `integer` but I got `Type not found` on ydata-profling package and did not find nothing in its docs.